# Angular Hybrid application unit testing

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-cli, karma-runner

How do I configure karma/test.ts/angular.json so it can pull in the *.spec.js files as well? I am using angluar-cli and do not want to use webpack in my project.

In my test.ts I am trying something like this:

```
const tsContext = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
const jsContext = require.context('../../lz-consumer-app/widgets/', true, /\.spec\.js$/);
// And load the modules.
tsContext.keys().concat(jsContext.keys()).map(tsContext);
```

Comment: Could you provide more details? By default angular is configured to run files with the .spec extension unless told otherwise. Are you trying to get it to run test files not in the angular project?

Comment: Like I mentioned it is the hybrid application. So I am trying to get 'ng test' configured so that it'd run *.js and .ts spec files.Angular CLI configures the test.ts as 
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
I am trying to also include the .js spec files written in angularjs 1.6